# Seaborn: Setting a binrange for a bivariate histplot

Tags: python, seaborn

Is it possible to set a binrange for a bivariate histplot in seaborn? I want use the binrange option to specify a point at which the bins will start. See for example this code:

```
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.histplot(penguins, x="bill_depth_mm", y="species", hue="species",binwidth=2)
```

[image: resulting bivariate histogram]

Now I want to start the bins at bill_depth_mm=12 and then use a binwidth of 2. I managed to set binwith to 2 but I can't figure out how to start the bins at 12. For a 'normal' histogram I know I can use the binrange for this:

```
sns.histplot(penguins, x="bill_depth_mm", hue="species", binwidth=2,binrange=(12,24))
```

[image: resulting normal histogram]

However this does not work for me when using a bivariate histogram:

```
sns.histplot(penguins, x="bill_depth_mm", y="species", hue="species", binwidth=2,binrange=(12,24))
```

[image: resulting figure]

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the edges of the bins using the `bins=` parameter

```
sns.histplot(penguins, x="bill_depth_mm", y="species", hue="species", bins=range(12,24,2))
```

[image]

Comment: This is functional but it would be better to answer the question directly IMO, as the requested functionality is possible: `binrange=((12,24), None)`. (Also the `binrange` is inclusive of the top value, but passing a `range` object isn't).